# How do I stop $watching in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I can set up a $watch on an AngularJS scope to be notified when the expression I am interested in has changed. But how do I stop watching once I lose interest?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

When calling `$watch` a function is returned that unregisters the bound expression.

E.g., to watch a variable `foo` only change once:

```
var unregister = $scope.$watch('foo', function () {
  // Do something interesting here ...
  unregister();
});
```

Comment: Just to make it clear: in the example above the 'unregister' callback is being called from within the watch function itself. This doesn't have to be the case, and code elsewhere in the app (i.e. outside of the watch function) could happily call it to ensure the watch function never gets called again.

Comment: Another note: When you register a watch, it is run once immediately, and then once again each time the value changes. So the exact code above will run the watcher-function once, and then deregister it before it reacts to any change in `foo`. A bit off topic, but I figured it's worth to mention.

Answer (score 22):

As an additional comment, but not answer - this is the same principle for killing event listeners as well.

```
var unregister = $rootScope.$on("listen-for-something-cool", function($event, params) {
   //Do cool stuff with params, then kill it
   unregister();
};
```

Just an addition I thought would be cool for anyone else to know...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how the accepted answer is working! For me it was not at all working.

I was using $watchCollection instead of $watch. I then tried to change it to $watch and applied the accepted answer but reached nowhere!!

The only thing which worked for me was:

```
var watchFoo = $scope.$watch('foo', function () {
  // Do something interesting here ...

    return;
});
```

**return;** was unregistering the watch and was breaking the watch Cycle. And it worked fine even after the  cycle was broken. It was able to detect changes made on the Array.

My code looked something like:

```
var watchFoo = $scope.$watchCollection('foo', function (newFoo, oldFoo) {
    
     if(condition) {
         // Do something interesting here ...      
          return;
     } else {
         // Do something else here ...
     }
     
    });
```

The accepted answer can be used if it works out for you otherwise this answer will come in handy!