# $watch for value changes in array of objects which is updated by ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular and have some difficulties with my first application.

I have array of objects retrieved from database: `$scope.result`
By clicking on each `ng-repeat` element through `ng-click` I push that element to `$scope.selectedTags` array and use another `ng-repeat` on the view. This second `ng-repeat` has two input fields. I want to `$watch` for changes on every element of `$scope.selectedTags` and if there are changes to make some calculations with the input values. I am using `angular.forEach` to `$watch` on every element in array but it doesn't work correctly if there are more than one element in the array.

---

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="application" ng-controller="controller">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="r in result" ng-click="addToSelectedTags($index)"><a href="#">{{r.name}}</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="t in selectedTags">{{t.name}}<input type="text" ng-model="t.n1" /> <input type="text" ng-model="t.n2" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

Javascript code:

```
  <script>
  var app = angular.module("application", []);
    app.controller("controller", function($scope){

    $scope.result = [
        {name: "first", n1: 2, n2: 6},
        {name: "second", n1: 7, n2: 1},
        {name: "third", n1: 4, n2: 9},
        {name: "fourth", n1: 5, n2: 2}

    ];
    $scope.selectedTags = [];

    $scope.addToSelectedTags = function(index) {
        var selectedtag = $scope.result[index];
        $scope.selectedTags.push(selectedtag);

      angular.forEach($scope.selectedTags, function(value, key) {
          $scope.$watchGroup(['selectedTags['+key+'].n1', 'selectedTags['+key+'].n2'], function(newval, oldval){
               if(newval[1] !== oldval[1]) {
                    $scope.selectedTags[key].n1 = newval[1]/oldval[1]*$scope.selectedTags[key].n1;
                    oldval[1] = newval[1];
               }
          });

       });
    };
});

    </script>
```

---

If there are two elements in `$scope.selectedTags` and change the value of the first element the `$watch` runs twice and make the wrong calculation. If there are three elements in `$scope.selectedTags` it runs three times and so on.
I tried to put the whole `angular.forEach` outside the `addToSelectedTags()` function but in that way it doesn't `$watch` for changes at all. Could you tell me how can I handle with this problem?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qAyT7Qbdz1MGnI39H4dQ?p=preview)

Comment: Why do want to apply watch explicitly ? Can i know what is your end goal

Comment: @Siddharth Pandey I tried with ng-change but I want to have oldValue and newValue to make my calculations. That's why I am using $watch. This is exactly what I want to calculate: $scope.selectedTags[key].n1 = newval[1]/oldval[1]*$scope.selectedTags[key].n1;

Comment: Have you tried watching just the array instead of every element inside it?

Comment: @Zonedark If I watch just the array how can I make the calculations with n1 and n2 on every change?

Comment: Well you could make a diff function that compares your old array and new array and extracts the element that changed.. Although that could work it's a bit overkill. I'll check if I can come up with something better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I got something working : [your updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/j3nHc7YYyTyJIwZHWdfK?p=preview)

Basically what caused the bug behaviour you had was that you created a new watch everytime you pushed a new element to selectedTags. By having multiple watches on an element, it calls your function for every watch currently watching over it. You only need one watch per element so I replaced the group watch by individual watches on your objects :

```
$scope.addToSelectedTags = function(index) {
        var selectedtag = $scope.result[index];
        $scope.selectedTags.push(selectedtag);

        $scope.$watchCollection('selectedTags[' + ($scope.selectedTags.length - 1)+ ']', function(newval, oldval){
                    //Not sure about the calculation you want, just change it to whatever behaviour you need
                    newval.n1 = newval.n2/oldval.n2*newval.n1
          });
    };
```

I am not sure about the operation you want though you may have to change it just under my comment. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you very much. I think this is what I need. I will try it to see if it works with my code and I will post feedback.

Comment: Sure, don't hesitate if you need anything

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work because of the 'index'. In $watch  the 'index' is the index of the 'result' array and not the 'index' of updated 'selectedTags' array. If I click on the 'result' array in random order the $watch doesn't work correctly.

Comment: I updated the plunkr link to fix it. I replaced index by the length of the selectedTags (minus one, to match the last element). Tell me if I understood correctly

Comment: Hello, Zonedark and sorry for the late answer. This works really very well, but when I try to make a function that remove an element from selectedTag array, the values of other array elements change. The error in console is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'n2' of undefined" I am using splice method to remove element. Here is updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/mY8zThjEgLULxfByEImC?p=preview. Do you have any solution about that problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello izzo, yes that's because you need to stop watching the elements when you delete them. I updated your plunker here : http://plnkr.co/edit/uRgrUK8B8vqNQq71odQz?p=info . You can check the documentation of angular watch, basicaly when you call the $watch method, the return of the call gives you a functions that when called, stops the watch. Here is an example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15715672/how-do-i-stop-watching-in-angularjs . Since you watch the array indexes and not the element inside it, you just need to stop watching the last element.

Comment: That's awesome. But now I have another problem with watching. After removing first element of the array, the second element becomes with index 0 and the $watch "sees" that there is change in the values of that index and make unnecessary calculations. I found that there is way to remove element form array without changing the index, but I'm not sure this will work with my code. Do you think this could be the solution here? I add console.log in $watch to see how the newval changes after removing element: http://plnkr.co/edit/YLKAiZVAJvz2aFz6R6MU?p=preview

Comment: Not at all. I added a variable to know if you have a pending remove. That should prevent the watch from operating once : http://plnkr.co/edit/kXy9FdbzlP9DSWBjUgDT?p=preview .

Comment: If I add all four elements and remove the first one, removeInProgress becomes false and make the watch again?

Comment: removeInProgress  changes back to false when the watch is immediatly called just after. I just noticed if you have more than one element it will work for the first one but not all of the others that also move though. But anyway, I already gave you a lot of help and you should be able to figure something out with what I just gave you!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I've learned really usefull things from our discussion.

Comment: No problem, happy to help! $watch in angular might be a bit complicated at first but it becomes easier! By the way, don't forget to "mark as answer" answers you find relevant. That might help other people in your case that are searching for answers!