# Call method on change of any fields only once using angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a form with multiple input fields in first tab. If the user changes any one of the field in this form, my other tabs should be disabled.

ng-chnage will hit every time the user inputs on the field though the tab disabling method already called on first time.

So, i want to disable the tabs on first change of any of the textbox. Later i dont want to hit that method or fire any event. Any idea how can i achieve this using angularjs?

Regards,

Comment: can you show your html

Comment: Sorry! I wanted to give the complete working plunker. Due to the complexity i could not add. Here is the plunker which gives the idea how it is implemented. i have added single input field. But i do have more in each of the tabs. http://plnkr.co/edit/0fGcwb0HUR6xbsOhFa4I?p=info

Comment: What about setting a flag after the first call to the function disabling the tabs? In this way on next "changes" event the function will not be called again. Alternatively you can use $watch instead of ng-change and stop watching after the first call (see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15715672/how-do-i-stop-watching-in-angularjs)

Comment: Yes, I have did the same way as of now. This will work...but let me use $watch and check how it works. Thanks